# How can I solve "Top-level use of w, timeout, j, and fsync is separated. Use writeConcern insted" in nestjs?

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

Currently, we are working on a project using nestjs + TypeOrm + MongoDB.

However, warning messages continue to appear, "Top-level use of w, wtout, j, and fsync is separated. Use writeConcern insted."

TypeOrm does not support mongoDB v4.0 or higher, it has been downgraded to v3.7.0.

However, I heard that this waning message was resolved in v3.5, but it still occurs. How can you solve this problem?

```
/// app.module.ts setting
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
            type: "mongodb",
            url: "-----",
            port: 27017,
            database: "-----",
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            entities: [Users]
        }),
        UserModule,
        AuthModule
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I have the same problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was on the url
My configuration URL was

```
url: process.env.MONGO_DATABASE_URL + '?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

I just remove w=majority and works fine

Comment: It's a problem that's already been solved, but in my case, it was for this reason as well. Thank you for your answer.